# Xcode push and pop view to save data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to log data from the FirstView (one text field and one button) to SecondView (UiTableView) for example contacts list. I would like to briefly explain my code.

I have added a NavigationController with TabBar in the AppDelegate.m;

```
UINavigationController *pointer = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = pointer;
[pointer setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
[pointer pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

And I have used a `[self.navigationController pushViewController:push animated:YES];` to push the data to the second screen but it always go to another NavigationController view as loop with BACK button, then I have used  `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` which it does not pass the data to the another view. Unless I close the program completely an open it back again. So is there a way to push and pop at the same time? Or could you please show me another way?

Thanks in advance.

Note I have shared my code in this link;
[Mycode](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NEuMa7g5PRrF64-E8-5aRAG51cFQN8dutn3Wnfgz63o/edit)

Comment: what kind of data are you passing?

Comment: I am passing a text to uitableview this text pushed to an array. I hope I understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a `singleton` class that manages this data.  Then you just call the same singleton class throughout your code, it should keep the same state throughout the lifetime of your app.

Or, a simpler way is to Set up "myArray" as a property in your App Delegate.. Then, in your class' implementation file, do something like this:

```
UIApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.myArray = newArray;
```

this assumes myArray and newArray has been properly initialized.

Comment: Avoid using appDelegate to store data.